# how to send input filed value to another page without form?

Tags: php, html

how to send input filed value to another page without form in PHP through  foreach loop?

```
<input type="text" size="3" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="<?php echo $product_quantity; ?>" />
```

Comment: More context is needed.

Comment: What do you mean by " through foreach loop"?

Comment: @Mahdi there are more then one input boxes for the quantity update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the values in **Session Array** and use it anywhere in the application. For Eg.

```
$_SESSION['valuesArray'] = array();

foreach($values as $value) {

         $_SESSION['valuesArray'] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Save value in **seassion** and then you can get it to other page
or you can save value in array if you are using foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either cookie or a session for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location: index.php?id=".$product_quantity);
```

make sure there will be no **print or echo** used before **header** function

Comment: That would be a bad practice I guess, because you're so prone to out put something before the `header` function get reached. I think it's not proper case to use `header` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use JavaScript to put the input value as a new parameter to the url of the other page.

```
<script>
function clickMe() {
    window.location.href="otherpage.php?param=<?php echo $product_quantity; ?>";
}
</script>
<input type="text" size="3" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="<?php echo $product_quantity; ?>" onclick=clickMe() />
```

At the other page "otherpage.php" you can just use $_GET to read out parameter.

This is just a quick and dirty solution...anyway it shows how to do it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

***1.php header for redirection***

```
header('Location: newpage.php?quantity=' $qty  );
```

***2.javascript :***

```
document.location.href = 'newpage.php?quantity=' + $('#quantity').val();
```

***3.Session***

```
session_start(); $_SESSION['qty']=1;
```

***4.cookie***

```
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;

setcookie("user", "Alex Porter", $expire);
```